# How to convert ASCII characters in a string in to normal characters?

Tags: php, encoding, ascii

How to change all ASCII character-set in a string to normal form with a single function?
for example:
for string "Hello Günter" when change into ASCII character-set is "text=Hello+G%C3%BCnter". I want reverse of this. I have string like "text=Hello+G%C3%BCnter" need to obtain "Hello Günter".
is there build in function in PHP?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: In the defence of ASCII characters, they are normal. You are dealing with URL encoded strings and can easily decode with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't ASCII, it is percent-encoded Unicode. More specifically, it is URL encoding.

Decode it with `urldecode`, or go the whole hog with `parse_str` which will take the data format and put it into an associative array.

```
<?php
    $foo = "text=Hello+G%C3%BCnter";
    echo $foo . "\n";
    $foo = urldecode($foo);
    echo $foo . "\n";

    $foo = "text=Hello+G%C3%BCnter";
    echo $foo . "\n";
    $foo = parse_str($foo, $bar);
    echo $bar['text'] . "\n";
?>
```

Normally you would only get data in this form through an HTTP request (e.g. in the query string) in which case reading it from `$_GET['text']` would retrieve the data after PHP had already automatically decoded it for you.

Comment: thankyou parse_str is all i needed.. since the data is in xml and send from another server.. how to i get value of each attribute separately?

Answer (score 0):

Check  sprintf() and chr() functions